# Failed to upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04, now APT throws errors

Tags: ubuntu, python, upgrade

After a failed upgrade I have a new icon on the top bar menu

[image: Error : BrokonCount >0]

And when I want to upgrade or install any package I have this problem

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
        Reading package lists... Done
        Building dependency tree       
        Reading state information... Done
        You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
        The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.5.1-4) but 3.5.3-1 is installed
         python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.5.3-1) but 3.5.1-4 is installed
                       Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.5.3-1) but 3.5.1-4 is installed
        E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I tried this command 'apt --fix-broken install' I have this message :

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libidl-2-0 libjson-c3:i386 libkeybinder0 liborbit2 libudev1:i386 libvte-common libvte9 libwings3 libwraster5 libwutil5 linux-headers-4.8.0-34
  linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-37 linux-headers-4.8.0-37-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-38 linux-headers-4.8.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-4.8.0-39 linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-41 linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-44
  linux-headers-4.8.0-44-generic linux-image-4.8.0-34-generic linux-image-4.8.0-37-generic linux-image-4.8.0-38-generic linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic linux-image-4.8.0-44-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-44-generic
  python-appindicator python-apport python-gconf python-gnome2 python-keybinder python-notify python-piston-mini-client python-problem-report
  python-pyorbit python-vte ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib python3
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib python3
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1484 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~); however:
  Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5-minimal
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A screenshot would have been better than a photo.

Answer (score 1):

The following was based on [this link](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5172146.html), which steps the commenter did worked for me.

1. Run `sudo nautilus` (in your Terminal)
2. Go to `/usr/local/bin` and delete any file/shortcut/folder with "python3" in it
3. Go to `/usr/local/lib` and do the same
4. Open a new Terminal (e.g., with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
5. Run

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install &&
        sudo apt -y update &&
        sudo apt -y upgrade &&
        sudo apt -y dist-upgrade &&
        sudo apt -f install &&
        sudo apt -y autoremove &&
        sudo apt autoclean &&
        sudo apt clean
   ```

   (You can combine it into fewer lines if you want.)
6. Reboot
7. Run number 5 again

Comment: (1) Where did you get these instructions?  I don’t see them at the link you provided.   (2) Can you explain any of this?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't express myself well. English is not my first language. They weren't instructions, actually, but steps the author did:
The author of the comment says in it that in the two machines -which he upgraded to U17.04- which presented the problem had "Python 3 at /usr/local", and that "the two that did not have Python 3 under /usr/local did not fail." So he "removed Python 3 from /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib." Which was what I tried to do (I'm just a regular user) and worked.